# Drawing in Vuforia - Pose Matrix

Tags: ios, graphics, opengl-es-2.0, vuforia

I'm working on a project where i need to draw simple opengl objects in vuforia scene even if no target is tracked.

```
if (state.getNumTrackableResults() <= 0)
{
    // Draw objects
}
```

The problem is i don't have a model view matrix. so anyone can tell me a way to generate one ?

Thanks

Comment: Please post your question in the link https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/ar-technical-discussion/ios

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to simply keep a target at your preferred reference point(such as the center of the screen.)

Get the modelViewMatrix corresponding to that. Store it and use it later as a reference to the center of screen when you're rendering(without target) in your project.